# PHP - Consecutive submits on same page

Tags: php, forms, submit

Can I make consecutive submits and stay on the same page?

I need one form to fill, and then second, and then third, and so on... and have to trigger different functions and forms based on the answer.For example:

```
  <form method="post">
       Sex?<input type="text" name="sex">
           <input type="submit" name ="submit_sex" value="Submit">
 </form>


<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit_sex'])){
         echo("Fist submit done");
      ?>

         <form method="post">
             Age?<input type="text" name="age">
                 <input type="submit" name ="submit_age" value="Submit">
          </form>
     <?php
         if(isset($_POST['submit_age'])){
             echo("Second submit done");
          }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean submitting the form and serving it back again?

Comment: I've uploaded the code again, and added details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, however it would look prettier/be more user-friendly if done with Ajax.  In your case though, it'll be more efficient to use conditional statements to detect which form to display, and for the sake of absolute minimum input validation, you should at least check for empty values:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['third_question']) && $_POST['third_question'] != "") {
            // store value of $_POST['third_question'] in a cookie
            // Last question answered, do what you need to next with all the values
        } elseif(isset($_POST['second_question']) && $_POST['second_question'] != "") {
            // store value of $_POST['second_question'] in a cookie
            Third Question? <input type='text' name='third_question' />
        } elseif(isset($_POST['first_question']) && $_POST['first_question'] != "") {
            // store value of $_POST['first_question'] in a cookie, then display next quesion
            Second Question? <input type='text' name='second_question' />
        } else {
            First Question? <input type='text' name='first_question' />
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to just do this on the browser side. You could do something like:

```
  <form method="post">
     <div id="sexInput">
       Sex?<input type="text" name="sex" />
           <input type="button" name="submit_sex" value="Submit" onClick="showAge()" />
     </div>
     <div id="ageInput" style="display:none;">
       Age?<input type="text" name="age" />
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

and have a function `showAge()` that hides the sexInput div and displays the ageInput div. This way it is really all one form, that gets submitted all at once at the end, but it is displayed to your user one part at a time.

Comment: But I don't know what the form will look like. Depending on the data received I will make calculations and then present the appropriate form that will lead to the next step of solving the problem.